# SharePoint - Web part to view remote list

Tags: sharepoint, listview, web-parts

Which web part and how to configure it to view a list from a different site collection?
Please note that I do not want to view a page but a list. For example view Announcements  from a different team site under a seperate site collection.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 3):

The [Data Form web part](http://masteringsharepoint.com/blogs/beagle/archive/2008/08/13/DFWP1.aspx) available through SharePoint designer can do this.

The Content Query Web Part (CQWP) which is part of the publishing infrastructure (requires MOSS) does not go across site collections.

Answer (score 0):

Re http://www.spelements.com/spanylistview/
The problem with this one is you have to be able to INSTALL it on the server.

If you do not have those permissions, it cannot be used.
Don't bother asking if they can be obtained. They can't.